# Can't deserialize JSON to Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json-deserialization

I'm doing some testing in my program and I wanted to transform APIGatewayProxyResponse into a object to access it's values.

So an example of what my APIGatewayProxyResponse.Body (it's a string) looks like:

```
"[{"date": "2020-03-06", "value": 35},{"date": "2020-03-09", "value": 233}]"
```

I wanted to turn this into a dictionary at first, but I realized that perhaps it's not possible because a dictionary has unique key values and here I have a "date" and "value" properties that aren't unique.

```
var dic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(APIGatewayProxyResponse.Body);
```

Had a error, which proved my concern:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

So I made an ResponseObject to achieve the same result

```
public class ResponseObject
    {
      public string date { get; set; }
      public double value { get; set; }
    }

var dic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(APIGatewayProxyResponse.Body,typeof(ResponseObject));
```

But had the same error! I don't understand, the browser can look at the response and recognises it's a JSON format, so why ins't the same happening in in ASP.NET?

Comment: Look at your JSON, what is the outermost token type? Object or array?

Comment: `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` should work, since you have keys that are unique within each array item. But a collection of strongly typed objects would be cleanest.

Answer (score 2):

Because your Json is an array, So, you can Deserialize with IEnumerable type.
Try this:

```
var dic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ResponseObject>>(APIGatewayProxyResponse.Body);
```